# Boost Hana Implement a custom Sequence

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I'm facing a situation where I usually would create a custom class by inheriting from `boost::hana::tuple`. For example, by using the following code,

```
template<typename ... args>
struct my_nonworking_custom_tuple_t : public boost::hana::tuple<args ...> //not working!!!
{
    using base = boost::hana::tuple<args ...>;
    //... all other stuff

    auto my_getter() const { return base::operator[](1_c); }
};
```

This, however, doesn't work as `boost::hana::tuple` is implemented as `final`.

Thus it seems I'm forced to use composition,

```
template<typename ... args>
struct my_custom_tuple_t
{
    //... all other stuff
    boost::hana::tuple<args ...> tup;
    auto my_getter() const { return tup[1_c]; }
};
```

However, as soon as I do that, the resulting class does not model the Hana concept "Sequence" anymore, so that I can't apply all the convenient Hana methods.

**What do I need to do to turn `my_custom_tuple_t` into a Hana Sequence?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't need to do this, but here is a guide for implementing your own `Sequence` as well as fulfilling requirements for other concepts in Boost.Hana. (The latter of which should be useful to end users who are not providing their own implementation of a tuple.)

Start with the **Minimal Complete Definition** (MCD) in the documentation for [`hana::Sequence`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Sequence.html)

There you will see that to implement a `Sequence` your data type must implement the `make` function as well as satisfy the requirements for [`Iterable`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html) and [`Foldable`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Foldable.html).

So the full list of Hana functions you must provide implementations for are as follows:

- `at`
- `drop_front`
- `is_empty`
- `make`
- `unpack`

Additionally, note that Boost.Hana has two tuple types `tuple` and `basic_tuple`. `basic_tuple` is more light weight so you should use that for your storage.

To use Boost.Hana's tag dispatching you can implement `hana::tag_of` or simply provide a `hana_tag` type alias as a member of your class.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <utility>

namespace mine {
    struct my_custom_tuple_tag { };

    template<typename ... args>
    struct my_custom_tuple_t {
        using hana_tag = my_custom_tuple_tag;
        //... all other stuff
        boost::hana::basic_tuple<args ...> tup;

        auto my_getter() const {
            return boost::hana::at_c<1>(tup);
        }
    };
}

namespace boost::hana {
    // Iterable

    template <>
    struct at_impl<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> {
        template <typename Xs, typename N>
        static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(Xs&& xs, N const&) {
            return at_impl<basic_tuple_tag>(std::forward<Xs>(xs).tup, N{});
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct drop_front_impl<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> {
        template <typename Xs, typename N>
        static constexpr auto apply(Xs&& xs, N const&) {
            return drop_front_impl<basic_tuple_tag>(std::forward<Xs>(xs).tup);
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct is_empty_impl<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> {
        template <typename Xs>
        static constexpr auto apply(Xs const& xs) {
            return is_empty_impl<basic_tuple_tag>(xs).tup;
        }
    };

    // Foldable

    template <>
    struct unpack_impl<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> {
        template <typename Xs, typename F>
        static constexpr auto apply(Xs&& xs, F&& f) {
            return unpack_impl<basic_tuple_tag>(std::forward<Xs>(xs).tup,
                                                std::forward<F>(f));
        }
    };

    // Sequence

    template <>
    struct make_impl<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> {
        template <typename ...Args>
        static constexpr auto apply(Args&& ...args) {
            return make_impl<basic_tuple_tag>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct Sequence<mine::my_custom_tuple_tag> : std::true_type { };
}
```

It is worth noting that the template for checking `Sequence` is simply an opt-in template specialization. I'm sure this is just a short cut to save on compile-time computations as the other concepts rely on checking for non-default implementations of their required functions.

https://godbolt.org/z/iaYBFq

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What is the reason for using a `basic_tuple` instead of `tuple`?

Comment: `hana::tuple` has the same constructors as `std::tuple` which make it very slow to instantiate. The author created `basic_tuple` to be a light weight equivalent since Hana already has `make`. Even `hana::tuple` itself uses `basic_tuple` as its storage (Ithink).

Comment: Yeah it does: https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/v1.6.0/include/boost/hana/tuple.hpp#L99. Thanks for the bounty! :D