# How can I make the std::vector class a Sequence so that it can be passed to boost::hana::group?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I want the following code to compile and work:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/group.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> x = {1,1,3,4};
    auto groups = boost::hana::group(x, std::equal_to<>{});
}
```

An attempt to compile errors like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++2a deleteme.cpp && ./a.out
In file included from deleteme.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/hana/group.hpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto boost::hana::group_t::operator()(Xs&&, Predicate&&) const [with Xs = std::vector<int>&; Predicate = std::equal_to<void>]’:
deleteme.cpp:6:44:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/hana/group.hpp:55:42: error: static assertion failed: hana::group(xs, predicate) requires 'xs' to be a Sequence
   55 |         static_assert(hana::Sequence<S>::value,
      |                                          ^~~~~
/usr/include/boost/hana/group.hpp:59:28: error: use of deleted function ‘static constexpr auto boost::hana::deleted_implementation::apply(T&& ...) [with T = {std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::equal_to<void>}]’
   59 |         return Group::apply(static_cast<Xs&&>(xs),
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   60 |                             static_cast<Predicate&&>(pred));
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/hana/core/dispatch.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/hana/drop_front.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/hana/concept/iterable.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/hana/at.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/hana/group.hpp:15,
                 from deleteme.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/hana/detail/dispatch_if.hpp:21:31: note: declared here
   21 |         static constexpr auto apply(T&& ...) = delete;
      |                               ^~~~~
```

Therefore I understand that the reason is that `std::vector` does not satisfy the concept of `Sequence`, but how do I enforce that it does?

I've been giving a look at `/usr/include/boost/hana/fwd/concept/sequence.hpp` and `/usr/include/boost/hana/concept/sequence.hpp`, but for now the template meta-metaprogramming in those files is still a bit to heavy for me to understand it without any help.

[This is an excerpt from Hana's documentation](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Sequence.html), which I think addresses the question. The point is that I don't how I can translate that prescriptions to code:

> For this reason, it is necessary to specialize
> the Sequence metafunction in Hana's namespace to tell Hana that a type
> is indeed a Sequence. Explicitly specializing
> the Sequence metafunction can be seen like a seal saying "this data
> type satisfies the additional laws of a `Sequence`", since those can't
> be checked by Hana automatically.

Comment: You can't enforce a standard library type that you didn't write to match a concept you didn't write??

Comment: @BaileyKocin id you really think this, give a shape to your thoughts and post an answer with the proof.

Comment: I'm questioning your question because its not logically possible.

Comment: It actually is impossible unless you supply your own compiler libs

Comment: @BaileyKocin then write an answer which proves your statement with something more specific than _you cannot_ and _it's impossible_.

Comment: Its common sense.

Comment: You didn't implement c++ how would you change a concept you didn't write?

Comment: @BaileyKocin because the library offers templates that I can specialize on other types to make those types satisfy concepts that makes those types suitable for the library's functions. Please read the edit to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to implement some of the concepts in Boost.Hana with types that involve different dimensions known only at run-time, Boost.Hana.Sequence and some of the concepts that are a part of its "Minimal Complete Definition" require length and elements to be known at compile-time.

- `Foldable` requires that the length be known at compile-time.
- `Iterable` requires that each element be accessible at compile-time.
- `Sequence` requires `Foldable` and `Iterable`.

The `group` function requiring a `Sequence` and the run-time length of `std::vector` make this impossible.

The section [*Computational Quadrants*](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introduction-quadrants) in the Boost.Hana manual elaborates on algorithms requiring compile-time vs run-time information.

(The `Group` concept is likely doable, but I don't think that is part of the question.)

Regarding the comments about specializing third party templates for standard types, it is possible but considered bad form. The solution is to make a wrapper type of some kind or provide your own concepts.

**Edit:**

A comment suggested an example of implementing `std::array` as a `Sequence` since its length is known at compile-time. While I can't find a silver bullet in the "Laws" of `Sequence` that forbid homogeneously typed lists, I can say that the premise of `Sequence` is working with heterogeneously typed data structures. Elements may contain run-time data, but all of the predicates in the algorithms rely exclusively on "compile-time" information so functions like `group` would be completely useless for `std::array`. (This is explained in the aforementioned link)

Comment: Concerning specializing [...], the excerpt, from Boost.Hana's documentation, at the end of my question seems to suggest that specializing is the way to go, so why do you say _bad form_? However, if the problem is `std::vector` having a runtime lenght, the could you give an example for `std::array`, which has a lenght known at compile time?

Comment: Specializing `Sequence` fine, but if you specialize it for a standard type, you are possibly breaking compatibility with versions of Boost.Hana that might elect to specialize it.

Comment: An example of implementing `Sequence`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879631/800347