# How can I make std::vector an Applicative in Boost.Hana without making it a Monad first?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, monads, boost-hana

As per the title, I'd like to understand how to make `std::vector` an `Applicative` but not a `Monad` (well, not yet). This is just for the sake of exploring and understanding Boost.Hana and functional programming.

### `Functor`

In [`hana/ext/std/vector.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/ext/std/vector.hpp), the `Functor` instance of `std::vector` is commented out, however, it seems to work fine ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sbK4YW)) if I uncomment it or copy it in my code.

### `Applicative`

However, there's no code in there to make it an `Applicative` (and, in turn, neither for making it a `Monad`), so I've looked into [`hana/concept/applicative.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/concept/applicative.hpp) to understand what must be implemented to do it myself. It needs an `_impl`ementation of `ap` and `lift`.

- As regards `lift`, would the following be a good enough implementation?

  ```cpp
  template <>
  struct lift_impl<ext::std::vector_tag> {
      template <typename T>
      static std::vector<std::decay_t<T>> apply(T&& value) {
          return {std::forward<T>(value)};
      }
  };
  ```

  On the other hand, since [`hana/lift.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/lift.hpp) contains a default implementation for `Sequence`s,

  ```cpp
      template <typename S>
      struct lift_impl<S, when<Sequence<S>::value>> {
          template <typename X>
          static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(X&& x)
          { return hana::make<S>(static_cast<X&&>(x)); }
      };
  ```

  I could alternatively just make `std::vector` a `Sequence`, which is easier:

  ```cpp
  template <>
  struct Sequence<ext::std::vector_tag> {
      static constexpr bool value = true;
  };
  ```
- Likewise, [`hana/ap.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/ap.hpp) also has an implementation for `Sequences`, but that uses `hana::chain`, as so it assumes that a `Monad` instance is defined in the first place.

  But what if I want to make `std::vector` an `Applicative` but not a `Monad`? I should customize `ap` myself. Is the following correct?

  ```cpp
  template <>
  struct ap_impl<ext::std::vector_tag> {
      template<typename F,
               typename X,
               typename Y = std::decay_t<decltype((*std::declval<F>().begin())(*std::declval<X>().begin()))>>
      static constexpr std::vector<Y> apply(F&& f, X&& x) {
          std::vector<Y> result; result.reserve(f.size() * x.size());
          for (auto const& f_ : f) {
              for (auto const& x_ : x) {
                  result.emplace_back(f_(x_));
              }
          }
          return result;
      }
  };
  ```

### The result

At first sight I thought it works, because in this simple case ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/P67sEr)) it does give the correct result:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto vplus = std::vector{std::plus<int>{}};
    auto vec = hana::ap(
            std::vector{std::plus<int>{}}, // wrapping 1 object in a vector
            std::vector<int>{10,20},
            std::vector<int>{1,2});
    BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(vec == std::vector<int>{11,12,21,22});
}
```

### Disappointment

However I see some weakness in my solution:

- I'm using `std::vector` instead of `lift` to wrap 1 function into a vector, which looks a bit non idiomatic, I believe;
- As soon as I think about the case where using `std::vector` instead of `lift` would be required, i.e. when I want to apply more than 1 function, I hit against the fact that, for instance, I can't put `std::plus` and `std::minus` in the same vector because they are function objects of different types.

For `hana::tuple` (or `std::tuple` if I defined the required instances for it), it's a piece of cake, because it can hold heterogeneous types:

```cpp
     // TUPLE EXAMPLE
    auto tuple = hana::ap(
            hana::make_tuple(std::plus<int>{}, std::minus<>{}),
            hana::make_tuple(10,20),
            hana::make_tuple(1,2));
    BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(tuple == hana::make_tuple(11,12,21,22,9,8,19,18));
```

### My question

Is there a way to make `std::vector` an `Applicative` in such a way that the `// TUPLE EXAMPLE` would work for `std::vector`?

Probably `std::function` and/or type erasure are necessary to accomplish the task?

Comment: `std::vector` cannot be a `hana::Sequence`. See this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63419720/800347

Comment: Does you question boil down to storing different functions in a vector? It seems you've already answered it.

Comment: @JasonRice I forgot that question. As regards this one, much of what I've written, I reasoned about it while crafting the question. I was kind of hoping that my deductions were wrong...

Comment: Boost.Hana's interfaces are geared more towards satisfying their own self-consistent laws which allows you to make use of the free model when extending it. Idiomatic/convenient interfaces are easy to put on top of these.